# First order non-linear ODE with quadratic and linear derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following ODE and I am not sure how to solve it. I have manipulated it a bit, but am not sure if my approach is the correct thing to do.

$$
0 = z^c-2(c-1)[1-z]y(z) + [2(1-z)-\mu]y'(z)-[\mu y']^2
$$

Dividing by $\mu^2$ to isolate the quadratic term

$$
0 = \frac{z^c}{\mu^2}-\frac{2(c-1)}{\mu^2}[1-z]y(z) + \frac{1}{\mu^2}[2(1-z)-\mu]y'(z)-(y')^2
$$

Letting

$$
\alpha(z) = \frac{1}{\mu^2}[2(1-z)-\mu]
$$

and

$$
\beta(z) = \frac{2(c-1)}{\mu^2}[1-z]
$$

This becomes

$$
0 = \frac{z^c}{\mu^2}-\beta y(z) + \alpha y'(z)-(y')^2
$$

or

$$
(y')^2  - \alpha y'(z) +\beta y(z) -\frac{z^c}{\mu^2}= 0
$$

However, I am not sure that it is acceptable to wrap the $1-z$ terms away into $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

If it *is* acceptable, then I will take the following square root of my expression

$$
y' = \pm \sqrt{\alpha y' -\beta y +\frac{z^c}{\mu}}
$$

This is not separable, so I don't think I can integrate it directly. Additionally, I am concerned about the "hidden" $1-z$ terms wrapped into $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: (1) As long as you remember that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in fact a functions of $z$, it is just a notational shortcut; no problem whatsoever. (2) Instead of taking the square root (why?), just solve the quadratic, and have $y'$ readily available.